# Is it wrong to design my appcelerator cross platform app with just one window?

Tags: appcelerator-studio

Sorry, this isn't a coding issue, not sure if i can ask this here. I'm using appcelerator to develop my Android/IOS app. I have noticed that for ios app usually a navigation Window is used to load all other windows. I'm doing it very differently. I'm using a single root window instead and i create views to be added to the window. I destroy the view when it's no longer required. I have tested this on the ios simulator and it works perfect, but im worried if there will be a problem with the app approval process with apple. I would like to find out if my way of doing it is acceptable and how do others do it?

Answer (score 0):

You won't have any problems with AppStore approval with such approach (of course if app fulfills other AppStore requirements).
It is hard to directly answer if it is a good approach. It depends on how you add these views, how your app looks like and how it behaves. Most common problems you may encounter:

- not releasing memory after removing views or a lot of memory used by not visible (but available) views,
- problem with back button on Android/Windows Phone - if you have only one window pressing back will close the app; to avoid that you will have to override default back button behavior,
- very complex code in single file (bad practice) or functionality difficult to track in many files (especially if you want views to communicate with each other) - it will complicate updates/modifications,
- Problem with checking if some objects are initialized - no 'open' event for window.

but on other hand:

- you can cut the speed required to open a new window,
- you will have full control over animating transitions between views.

In my opinion such approach is not very good (efficient) and windows serve their purpose. But everything depends on what you want to achieve in your app. If you have few plain views and expect quick transitions between them than it may be the best way.